# PHP Dotenv environment vars persists across requests

Tags: php, environment-variables

I'm using the library [PHP Dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) to load and set environment variables for development of a PHP application.

I noticed that "sometimes" `Dotenv\Loader\getEnvironmentVariable()` returns something that is not `null` when called at the very start of the request.

It means that what is set by [`Dotenv\Loader\setEnvironmentVariable()`](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/blob/master/src/Loader.php#L328-L349) "sometimes" persists across requests.

This happen with no consistence, it just appear on some random requests, even if **nothing** changed between not working and working requests.

I tried a lot of different setups, and this only happens on Windows + Apache.

Considering following lines are in there:

```
$_ENV[$name] = $value;
$_SERVER[$name] = $value;
```

Is it possible that OPcache is the "culprit"? If so, why only on Windows?

Or might be possible that what is set by `apache_setenv()` might persist across requests? The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-setenv.php) is not very clear on the regard.